# Recommended sound effects library for designing system sounds?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, sound-libraries

I would like to create some system sound effects for a sporting device. The device needs sound effects for actions such as play, stop, pause, error, clicking a slider etc.

Is there a free sound library that I could use for this?

Is there useful literature useful for designing my own sounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, I found some free effects by googling for UI Sound Effects and making some of my own in Logic Pro X. I mainly used ones I found on here:

http://opengameart.org/

In future I may purchase one of the sample libraries you've suggested as it would save a lot of time and be much more professional, however I was essentially looking for free samples.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.affordableaudio4everyone.com/Affordable%20SFX%204%20Everyone/HudMenuInterfaceToolbox.html

or

http://www.ueberschall.com/de/product/162/Future-FX;jsessionid=z2l2yv6mqafztz7eqm8jo2gd

or

http://library.empty-sea.com/product/ui-one

The iFX series by Zero-G is also very useful

Comment: Thanks for this, you led me to improve my search, instead of googling "system" sounds I tried "UI" sounds and this was much better in returning results.

Answer (score 2):

The Boom library "Sci-fi" and "interface" could help you. As always their sounds are really great, well classified, good metadata for Soundminer, they always give a bunch of sounds which is good to avoid to have the same repeteting sound. You should take a look at.

Answer (score 1):

Friendly greetings Simon!

Beyond a sample library, what about a dedicated tool to create UI samples? It's not free but I encourage you to consider the productivity and/or fun you might experience with Soundmorph's Galactic Assistant, it's an app designed to make UI sounds (marketed as being futuristic, but not limited to that): http://soundmorph.com/index.php?page=soundpacks&spack=ga

I don't have it but trust them by way of friends vouching for their stuff and reputation.

Would ♥ to hear what you ended up creating.

Answer (score 1):

i just put up my own free library, with some gui & button sounds: http://www.nilsmosh.com/sample-libraries , happy if you can use it for your project!

Comment: Project was 2 years ago, but thanks for answering as others may find it useful as well! +1 to you Sir.